# Diagram Type for Service Connections?

Tags: uml

Just wondering what's the correct UML Diagram type to show Service Connection? Essentially saying that "Client A needs a function GetFoo that needs to return items whose quantity is bigger than 20" and "Client B needs a function GetFoo that returns all items"?

A Component Diagram looks correct, but already very concrete in terms of types and very vague in terms of single functions. Composite Structure maybe?

Eventually this is used during planning to decide which functions a service actually needs to have (e.g., an inner GetFoo and two outer GetHeavyFoo/GetAllFoo functions)

Answer (score 0):

I think the composite structure diagram will work for you. However, in my opinion you should combine it with sequence or communication diagram or both - whichever works best for you. I also suggest you check all the [uml diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language#Diagrams_overview) and compare them and then decide which ones are best suited for you.

Answer (score 0):

Component diagram is a good solution as well as Sequence.

If you are a beginner in UML you can also just create a class diagram and add a constraints on a method. It would do the job and be easy to understand by the developer team.
It used to be OCL in UML 1.X but now with UML2 direct access to the metamodel you can just create any constraints directly in the model without any transformation. I use EclipseUML Omondo and don't want to use OCL because too complex for a very limited return on investment. My workaround is also better because I can write whatever I want and directly put it inside my class diagram without having two different models (e.g. one for UML and one for OCL).